# Find out the audio channel that has LTC

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I need to be able to check a video file for any audio channels that have LTC (Linear Timecode) I tried using ffmpeg and ffprobe but I am only getting general info about the audio stream (like number of channels)

Is there a command that returns specific info about each audio channel? If yes, what field should I look at to decide if that specific audio channel is LTC?

Tentacle Sync Studio app seems to know which channel is LTC and automatically mutes it.

[image]